# DIV Positioning — Cross Browser Issue

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a page that should have text on the left and a form on the right. It looks (and renders) properly on most browsers (including Firefox, Chrome, and Safari).

Some versions of IE, however, keep the form in the correct position (top-right), but push the text all the way to the bottom of the page.

Here's the code used to position the form:

```
.custom #conversion_form {
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid #999;
background-color: #e9e9e9;
padding: 25px 30px 25px 25px;
float: right;
display: block;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

What tag(s) to I need to add to keep the text in the top left/avoid having it get pushed down?

Demo: http://rainleader.com/signup

Screenshot (How it Should Look): [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating a side by side effect it's always best to float the left content left, float the right content right, and `overflow:hidden;` both.

If you still see a problem, wrap both of the content in a `<div>` and `overflow:hidden;` that.

Comment: I did that and it pushes the right element all the way down: http://rainleader.com/what-we-do/analyze/

Comment: It looks like that's because the left DIV and the right DIV width combined is larger than the container width.

Comment: The container width is set by Wordpress. How would you advise I fix it without hacking into Wordpress?

Comment: Change the width of the div#mf7

Comment: I changed the width of the wrapping "float_left" and "float_right" div's. Seems to have solved the problem. Look good on your end?

Comment: This is not a "cross browser" issue. This is an "it doesn't work in IE" issue. We don't adjust markup that works in every modern browser just for the sake of IE.

Comment: @Rob Then add a stylesheet for IE, however if you style correctly, you will rarely need to make use of a second stylesheet for IE only.

Comment: If you style it correctly, you almost always have to do something for IE to make it work right. That's why the OP has markup that works in any modern browser but IE screws it up. Situation normal for IE. There's nothing wrong with what he wrote. The problem is always IE.

Answer (score 2):

I'd create two divs, one for the text other for the form.

I always use the center 50% on the left attribute and use margin-left or marging-right to handle de position of the divs independently of resolutions.

See this example:

Div for the text, put the text within the div:

```
.div_left_text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-250px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

Div for the form, put the form within this div:

```
.div_right_form {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right:250px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

This should create two areas one in the left another in the right independently.